# How to configure to ignore tokenization for some Traditional Chinese keywords in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, elasticsearch-plugin, icu, chinese-locale

I use ICU plugin in elasticsearch to tokenize Traditional Chinese
 ex: keyword 珍珠奶茶 will be tokenized to 2 tokens 珍珠 and 奶茶
but in some keywords I don't want to be tokenized

so I want to configure to let elasticsearch to ignore to tokenize for my list of keywords (100 keywords)

I found the way to configure it here
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/analysis-icu-tokenizer.html#_rules_customization
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/custom-bundles.html

but I can't figure out how to configure for a list of Traditional Chinese keywords

I very appreciate if anyone can help me on it.

Comment: sorry, if the question is not clear, could you put comments to let me know which part need to be more clearer?

Comment: I configured rule in this file config/KeywordTokenizer.rbbi
and use rule in elasticsearch schema like this
"rule_files" : "Hant:KeywordTokenizer.rbbi, Hans:KeywordTokenizer.rbbi, Hani:KeywordTokenizer.rbbi"  (I want to apply for Chinese both Tradition and Simplified)